# need guid to start implementing Sybil Attack in Vanet

Tags: omnet++, sumo

I'm amateur in working with omnet++. I want to use omnet++ and Sumo to implement Sybil Attack in Vanet. Does anyone know a source or tutorial which helps me to implement it?

Comment: Look for F2MD, code available on GitHub

Answer (score 1):

Check if neta framework is useful as it implement some Manet attacks. https://omnetpp.org/download-items/NETA.html
A better place to start for beginners is tic toc tutorial. Follow it by learning veins.car2x.org